# Angular async validator stuck

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous

I have quite a big reactive form, which I display on two tabs (each hidden/displayed by *ngIf). I'm passing necessary FormGroups / Arrays to those tabs through Inputs(). On the second tab there's a list of items build on FormArray and some of it's FormControls have async validators like this:

```
static ibanValidator(service: ValidationService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        if (!control.value) {
            return of(null);
        }

        return control.valueChanges.pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            take(1),
            switchMap(v => {
                return service.validateIBAN(v)
            }),
            map((result: ValidationStatus) => {
                let e = null;
                if (result !== ValidationStatus.OK) {
                    e = {};
                    e[result.toLowerCase()] = 'IBAN'
                }
                return e;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I stay on the second tab (when I change the field value then the validator makes the async call and the status goes -> PENDING -> VALID.
But when I go back to the first tab then on the view creation angular calls:
_updateTreeValidity -> and for each field updateValueAndValidity which causes async validator to get called and I get PENDING status on fields with async validators since control doesnt changed
(_pendingChange = false).
How to handle this properly? Am I doing something wrong? Should I build each tab on separate Form?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to separate the form. And it has nothing to do with async validator.

I think the reason is that when switching to the first tab, you only removed the **second form elements** from the .html file, but you didn't update Fromgroup in the .ts file. Because of that, the second form group validator gets called every time you make a change to the form.

Look at the simplified code below.

```
new FormGroup({
  firstFormGroup: new FormGroup(''),
  secondFormGroup: new FormGroup('', SomeValidator), // Remove this form control whenever you want to remove form tags from the thml page.
});
```

Comment: I dont update FormGroup because I dont want to, I keep my whole state in it. it seems to me as a most conveniet way, rather than updating the form and set its value from the state variable every time user changes the tab, I prefer to have a big form which stores the state but display only a part of it. Is it possible to make the form check the state only for FormControls that actually changed?

Comment: In that case, You might need to separate the form and combine them when needed.